# caffe: how to design lmdb for bounding box regression

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, bounding-box, lmdb

I am trying to import the SUN RGB-D dataset into lmdb format so that caffe can train for the bounding box regression. I see for imagenet conversion, there is a file putting the filename and the class label on one row. How can I prepare the data so I can label an object by four point coordinates? There are about 10 objects recognized in the ground truth image, so one image should contain around 10 * 8 values for the regression result.

Comment: Maybe you can follow this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095280/how-to-predict-float-vector-labels-with-caffe/38137119#38137119)

Comment: Refer this site https://xiaoyuliu.github.io/2018/02/23/combine-datasets-into-lmdb-for-caffe/