# HDF5Data Processing with Caffe's Transformer for training

Tags: python, io, caffe, hdf5, transformer-model

I am trying to load data to the network, since I need a custom data input (3 tops: 1 for data image, 2 for different labels) I load the data with HD5F files. It looks similar to this:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "img"
  top: "alabels"
  top: "blabels"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "path_to_caffe/examples/hdf5_classification/data/train.txt"
    batch_size: 64
  }
}
```

I want to preprocess the images using Caffe's own Transformer (for standard), how can I do this when I have to initialize the Transformer with data blob of a network model:

```
transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
```

All the examples I have found first loads a pre-trained net and sets a transformer with its data blob/shape, but I couldn't find any for training. Thanks.

Comment: how about using the transformer when writing the data to hdf5?

Comment: @shai Can I do that using Caffe's own Transformation? I want to use Caffe's own functions for standardization. How should I initialize Transformation? It seems like it takes the data blob when being initialized, even though it is just for its shape.

Comment: To elaborate, the Class Transformer requires the Net  as parameter:
Class definition: Transform input for feeding into a Net.
Parameters: net : a Net for which the input should be prepared

Comment: And for preprocess, the parameters are:
        in_ : name of input blob to preprocess for, 
        data : (H' x W' x K) ndarray
       and it returns:
        caffe_in : (K x H x W) ndarray for input to a Net

Comment: It is possible to write own functions I suppose but it seems Transformer could work in batches and I would prefer to follow Caffe standard for this experiment.