# Neural Network with Matlab toolbox or caffe ?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

I want to develop a convolution neural network with Matlab.
I read that there is a frame work, Caffe, often used for that and there is also a Matlab toolbox.

I see a lot of people using Matlab WITH Caffe but I don't really get what Caffe is for..

Can I develop my CNN only using the Matlab toolbox (and the parallel computing toolbox) without Caffe or do I need to work with Caffe ?

Comment: you dont need caffe, use it if it helps you. I mean, in theory you dont even need Matlab toolboxes, you coudlcode it yourself

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question is **Yes** you can develop CNN only using Matlab.
As I understand you also have Neural Network so you can use built-in functions for this. Here is the example from [official website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/convolutional-neural-networks.html).

Furthermore you can download pre-trained CNN from [matlab web](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-deep-learning.html#zmw57dd0e916) and watch the code (it's really helpful sometimes).

And the third - there are some handmade models of CNN you can download from File Exchange and other websites. [This one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24291-cnn-convolutional-neural-network-class) for example.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much !

So why people are using Caffe ? Is it just because it is free ? Or is it really better ?

Comment: @Alex_Strasbourg by the I found this one theme: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081408/python-or-matlab-for-caffe

Comment: @Alex_Strasbourg I never worked in Caffe so I can't give you detailed response what is better. I suppose the algorithms are the same so there is no a big difference. I suggest you to think what is more comfortable for you to use (if you never used any of them start for Caffe it's free, if you already have matlab experience - use matlab) because you know create adequately working neural net is a some type of engineering art.

Comment: Okay thank you. I am used to work with Matlab so I will continue with it

Comment: @Alex_AMC I'm working for neural networks too now, but not for image recognition. And matlab is strong enough for my tasks!
By the way if my answer were helpful tag it as accepted!