# How to convert hdf5 format to caffemodel format in caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, matcaffe

Basically I am using using caffe for deep learning. Now I finetuned a network for my own dataset and saved my model in hdf5 format which is `.h5` extension.

Now I want to classify images using matcaffe. matcaffe understands only .caffemodel format for trained model.
So is there any way to convert hdf5 file to caffemodel?

Comment: how did you save the hdf5 model during finetuning?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the preferred format for the caffemodel file in your `solver.prototxt`. Simply set

```
snapshot_format: BINARYPROTO
```

See [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L194) for more information.

---

Alternatively, you can use python interface ([which is by far better than the matlab interface for caffe, IMHO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33081408/1714410)):

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Net('/path/to/deploy.prototxt', '/path/to/caffemodel.h5', caffe.TEST)
net.save('/path/to/just.caffemodel')
```

Comment: Shai thanks for your answer, actually in start i did not know that there are different snapshot formats so i saved in hdf5 format. I ran 1lakh iterations so it was not possible for me to run it again.

Comment: But i found a way around for this and it worked for me.

Comment: @RafayZiaMir can you elaborate on the workaround you found? would you post it as an answer?

Comment: Shai, i think that way around should not be an answer, because what i did that after 1lakh iterations i had an hdf5 format model. Then i changed the snapshot format in solver file. Then i loaded my trained model and then started finetuning on it but now this time it saved the model in caffemodel format. So basically its what you are saying but i just again finetuned my network and saved in caffemodel format.